# Can't get WiX feature action state working

Tags: wix, wix3.6

So I have simple conditional property set:

```
<SetProperty Id="STOP_CHROME" Action="Set" Value="1" After="CostFinalize">
  <![CDATA[(&FEAT_Chrome_Hpr=3)]]>
</SetProperty>
```

The strange thing about it, is that property is always set, despite having in logs, for example:

```
MSI (s) (70:28) [14:39:33:398]: Feature: FEAT_Chrome_Hpr; Installed: Absent;   Request: Null;   Action: Null
```

I assume my order of SetProperty action may be wrong, however I'm not sure which one is correct. But AFAIK `After="CostFinalize"` is correct for my case (after features were selected).

**UPDATE**. Found no solution to my question. I adwise you, not to add new answers, since I can't really test it now. Moderators are free to remove this question completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found no solution to my question. Also I adwise you, not to add new answers, since I can't really test it now. Moderators are free to remove this question completely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try scheduling it before CostFinalize. This is because the [SetProperty](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) element creates a Type 51 Custom action. A [Type 51](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Custom Action can be used to affect a property used in a condition on a component or a feature only when it is scheduled before CostFinalize.

Comment: I think I've tried that already, it didn't worked. Honestly I can't really test your answer one more time (to doublecheck) since I decided to do it some other way, but I appreciate your efforts.